# Where to Find Documentation for GPIO Controller Pins of Pi4?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, bare-metal

I'm beginning bare metal programming on the Pi4. As a simple 'hello world' equivalent I'm trying to get the ACT led to blink. I have seen references that it is tied to the BCM2711 GPIO Controller pin 16. However, looking at the [BCM2711 datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/)  I can't find any references to this. Is this information available in a datasheet or an official documentation source somewhere?

Comment: it's different on pi3 and pi4 - read the README in boot/overlays folder for some insight - though this won't give you an answer (i.e. it mentions a GPIO expander and a special driver ...

Comment: Good question! Welcome to RPi SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BCM2711 peripherals documentation can be found on the Foundation website.
https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/bcm2711/bcm2711-peripherals.pdf

The GPIO is a superset of the earlier GPIO i.e. it is identical EXCEPT some pins have additional modes and the peripheral address differs between models. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/peripheral_addresses.md

AFAIK there is no public documentation for the on-board interfaces e.g. ACT LED.

Exploring the [gpiochip](https://www.beyondlogic.org/an-introduction-to-chardev-gpio-and-libgpiod-on-the-raspberry-pi/) implementation in latest Raspberry Pi OS gives some hints about the on-board GPIO functions.

```
gpioinfo pinctrl-bcm2835
```

Update:
The following may be of interest re the expansion GPIO.

```
gpioinfo raspberrypi-exp-gpio
gpiochip1 - 8 lines:
    line   0:      "BT_ON"       unused  output  active-high 
    line   1:      "WL_ON"       unused  output  active-high 
    line   2: "PWR_LED_OFF" "led1" output active-low [used]
    line   3: "GLOBAL_RESET" unused output active-high 
    line   4: "VDD_SD_IO_SEL" "vdd-sd-io" output active-high [used]
    line   5:   "CAM_GPIO"       unused  output  active-high 
    line   6:  "SD_PWR_ON" "sd_vcc_reg"  output  active-high [used]
    line   7:    "SD_OC_N"       unused   input  active-high
```

Comment: Why would they not include this information in the BCM2711 datasheet?

Comment: @RyanMcClue Because it has nothing to do with the SOC this is the design of the Pi board and the extra hardware they use. Why it is not documented is one of life's mysteries.

Comment: This is a really useful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Edward Chamberlain

Reviving this thread in Jul 2023 - I cannot find the pinout anywhere!

Any luck?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/130965)